# How to print a huge image as multiple tiles using Photoshop CS4

Tags: print-design

I have a design in Photoshop CS4 that I want to print on multiple glossy sheets of paper to create a wall-sized image.

Using the slice tool I cut it into 99 pieces, each of which I want to print on an 8.5 * 11, horizontally oriented.

How can I prepare each slice for printing? Should I create a new document for each, and if so how should I prepare the document/image size in order to make each full slice to be a full page, without losing resolution?

Comment: ^ A similar issue, but not quite a duplicate. This deals more with print, and that thread with web. Thank you, nevertheless, Joonas!

Comment: The way I see it, you are asking 2 additional questions, but otherwise both questions are asking about the same thing. I don't see how that question is about web specifically. Some of those methods might not be fit for web, but most certainly all of them are fit for print.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only valid if you own Adobe Illustrator too.

Create an Illustrator file with multiple artboards of the desired dimensions (8.5x11) arranged to match the image proportions, with no gap between each artboard. Import your PSD and stretch it across all artboards, then export your Illustrator document as 1 file per artboard.